# How to use html webworkers with angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, web-worker

I am handling very hight dataset with type arry. While iterating through this arrays my application gets performance hit. I want to use webworkers which will perform manipulation operations on huge array and it will directly return the processed dataset back to application.web

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://github.com/vkiryukhin/ng-vkthread I develop it exactly for such kind of tasks. It let you easily export function in a thread, execute it and get result in UI. Even more: you can download data directly in a thread rather than transfer it from UI to a thread.

the very basic usage is:

```
/* function to execute in a thread */
function foo(n, m){
    return n + m;
}

/* create an object, which you pass to vkThread as an argument*/
var param = {
      fn: foo      // <-- function to execute
      args: [1, 2] // <-- arguments for this function
    };

/* run thread */
vkThread.exec(param).then(
   function (data) {
       console.log(data);  // <-- thread returns 3
    },
    function(err) {
        alert(err);  // <-- thread returns error message
    }

);
```

Doc and examples: http://www.eslinstructor.net/ng-vkthread/demo/